# failed to push some refs (TFS) after creating new branch: [remote rejected] error File upload already completed

Tags: git, tfs

I was working quite a while with a git repo (remote is hosted on a TFS) on the master branch without any problems. However, I decided to create a new branch (TEST2) to update some stuff (basically to update several subtrees). But when it came to push the branch, git returned an error as follows:

```
$ git push -u origin TEST2
Counting objects: 212, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (154/154), done.
Writing objects: 100% (212/212), 1.63 MiB | 1.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 212 (delta 155), reused 102 (delta 54)
remote: Analyzing objects... (212/212) (1598 ms)
error: remote unpack failed: error File upload already completed.
remote: Storing packfile...
To http://zzz/zzz/zzz
 ! [remote rejected]   TEST2 -> TEST2 (File upload already completed.)
error: failed to push some refs to 'zzz/zzz/zzz'
```

I'm logged in as administrator on the TFS, so there shouldn't be any issues with the credentials...

Comment: It might be due to these following reasons, The local repository may be corrupted or disk space in the server hosting Stash is full. The issue is nothing to do with the credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LethalProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7640269/lethalprogrammer) pointed me to the right direction...
The Express Version of SQL Server 2014 (which I used in my TFS environment) is limited to 10GB of data - And this point was reached.

Answer (score 0):

Test at my side, everything works correctly.

1. Please check if your account miss the permissions on the Team
   Foundation Server to git push for the repo/branch.
2. Try using the `--no-thin` option of git push.

   `$ git push --no-thin origin TEST2`

> **-u**
>
> **--set-upstream**
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less
>   git-pull[1] and other commands. For more information, see
>   branch..merge in git-config[1].
>
> **--[no-]thin**
>
> These options are passed to git-send-pack[1]. A thin transfer significantly ?reduces the amount of sent data when the sender
>   and receiver share many of the same objects in common. The default is
>   --thin.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (low rep) to @Silvio's answer so hopefully I can add my two cents here. Thanks to @Silvio for pointing me in the right direction!

I've been searching for a few hours why I was getting the incredibly uninformative `! [remote rejected] master -> master (One or more errors occurred.)` error message after pushing to a new remote ADO repository.

I was able to trace it to the maximum database file size of 10GB for SQL Server Express Edition which is what we are using for our Azure DevOps on premise server.

I was pushing a repo over 2GB and the DB itself was already just shy of 10GB, hence the `remote unpack failed` error when trying to unpack.

Upgrading to Standard or Enterprise SQL Server editions will remove that max DB file size cap that is enforced on the Express Edition.